# How to compare 2 elements of a column with each other?

Tags: r, correlation

I am using R. I have a column with 4 elements `{car, bus, walk, train}`. I would like to compare the car and bus with each other with the help of the 3 other columns. How can I do this?

For example, suppose that the other column is `male/female`, I would like to know how many are male or female for car and bus.

Comment: It is kind of row correlation

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://www.statmethods.net/stats/frequencies.html) can be useful to you?

Comment: Do you want a table of counts for each pair of categories? Like `table(d$vehicle, d$gender)`?